# Copy text, images, tables, ALL formatting, margins from on GDoc to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

After trying a few mail merge scripts, I decided t write my own. My merge script runs as a separate fiIt reads a template from a GDoc, reads data from a GSpreadsheet, and merges it either into Gmails or into a new GDoc - one page / email per SS row.

The problem is that it doesn't copy text formatting, margins or images into the Gmail or new GDoc ... only the plain text.

I am using **DocumentApp.openById > getActiveSection > getText()** to capture the text.

Here is the code in GDoc http://goo.gl/fO5vP 
I can't seem to share a script so I had to put it in a doc. Copy it to a new script and it will be color coded.

Comment: please see edit2, I updated my code with a fully working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should copy the template first using `DocsList` so you start with a "complete" initial document.

```
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(docIDs[0]);// get the template model, in this sample I had an array of possible templates, I took the first one
  var newmodelName=template.substr(0,11)+'multipage'+template.substring(18);// define a new name, do what you need here...
  var baseDocId = DocsList.copy(template,newmodelName).getId();// make a copy of firstelement and give it new basedocname build from the serie(to keep margins etc...)
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(baseDocId);// this is the new doc to modify
```

then use the [document class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document) that has a direct [replaceText method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document#replaceText)

---

EDIT : about your secondary question, here is a suggestion on how you could do. It works nicely except for `inlineImage`, I'll keep looking at this. You could also make the script more universal by adding other element types...

```
function myFunction() {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(key);// get the template model
  var newmodelName='testcopy';// define a new name, do what you need here...
  var baseDocId = DocsList.copy(template,newmodelName).getId();// make a copy of firstelement and give it new basedocname build from the serie(to keep margins etc...)
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(baseDocId);// this is the new doc to modify
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();
  body.appendPageBreak();
  var totalElements = body.getNumChildren();
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var element = body.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
      body.appendTable(element);
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
      body.appendListItem(element);
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE )
      { var blob = body.getChild(j).asInlineImage().getBlob();
       body.appendImage(blob); }
  }
}
```

---

**Edit 2** Thanks to [@Fausto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634207/fausto-r), here is a fully working version. Inline images are included in a paragraph so we had to dig one level more to get the blob...

```
function myFunction() {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(key);// get the template model
  var newmodelName='testcopy';// define a new name, do what you need here...
  var baseDocId = DocsList.copy(template,newmodelName).getId();// make a copy of firstelement and give it new basedocname build from the serie(to keep margins etc...)
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(baseDocId);// this is the new doc to modify
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();
  body.appendPageBreak();
  var totalElements = body.getNumChildren();
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var element = body.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      if (element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() != 0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
        var blob = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
        body.appendImage(blob);
      }
      else body.appendParagraph(element.asParagraph());
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
      body.appendTable(element);
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
      body.appendListItem(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working! Any ideas how to copy text, formatting and images within a document and copy it to the second page of the doc?? Also what does the [0] in "docIDs[0]" do?

Comment: Thx, I added some comments to explain, this is a part of a bigger script and I left some parts that are not related to the question... sorry bout that. Now I hope it is more clear. As for your oher question I'll try to update my answer later in the day ;-) no time now...